# Where is Crescent Moon Bay?

Tags: real-location, vampirates

The *Vampirates* series is set five hundred years in the future, in a world much more watery than the present-day one. From the synopsis of the first book:

> The year is 2505. The oceans have risen. A new era of piracy is dawning.

At the start of the series, our heroes, Connor and Grace Tempest, have lived all their lives in Crescent Moon Bay. Do we know where this is meant to be, in terms of real-life geography? Even though "the oceans have risen", presumably any piece of dry land in 2505 is also on land in the present day.

To put it another way: where in the world are Grace and Connor from?

Comment: Seems to only be a Californian Half Moon Bay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the author's [official website](http://www.vampirates.co.uk/the-world-of-vampirates/item1/), Crescent Moon Bay is on the east coast of Australia, in roughly the same place as [Byron Bay, New South Wales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byron_Bay,_New_South_Wales).

> *Where better to start your voyage than Crescent Moon Bay on the East
> Coast of Australia? Here’s where Connor and Grace Tempest spent the
> first thirteen years of their lives, living with their dad, Dexter
> Tempest, the town’s lighthouse keeper.*
>
> *As some of you may have guessed, I was inspired by the Australian
> coastal town of Byron Bay and the lighthouse at Cape Byron, which
> marks the most easterly point of the continent.*
>
> *I should say though (especially to any Australians reading this!) that
> any resemblance to Byron Bay begins and ends with the topography!
> Byron Bay is a pretty idyllic spot, but Crescent Moon Bay is a
> dead-end town – the kind of place you wouldn’t want to linger any
> longer than you had to…*
>
> <sub><sup>[CRESCENT MOON BAY - THE WORLD OF VAMPIRATES - Justin Somper](http://www.vampirates.co.uk/the-world-of-vampirates/item1/)</sup></sub>